# NetworkManager refuses to manage my WLAN interface

Tags: wireless, 12.10, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome 3.6 on a brand-new Samsung NP900X4C.

The installer detected the wireless adapter, took in the SSID and WPA passphrase, wrote these into `/etc/network/interfaces` and connected perfectly.

Once installation was finished I wanted to switch to using NetworkManager to manage the wireless adapter, since this is much more convenient than fiddling with `/etc/network/interfaces` every time I find a new hotspot.

Therefore I edited `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to set:

```bash
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

When I rebooted NetworkManager, the problems started:
 - The NetworkManager tray applet changed from saying `device not managed` to `device not ready`
 - I lost all internet connectivity as wlan0 would not associate to the Access Point
 - if I set `managed=false` in `NetworkManager.conf` and restarted both NetworkManager and networking services from the command-line, the Gnome desktop "semi-crashed" and lost all its Window Decorations, the panel, the launcher and basically became unusable.

However if I restart the computer completely after setting `managed=false`, wlan0 once again works perfectly.

Comment: In `managed=false` mode, wlan0 works after reboot because ifup configures it at boot time (if /e/n/i contains `auto wlan0`). In `managed=true` mode, ifup doesn't bring interfaces up automatically; but then NetworkManager *should* do so. I don't know why it said `device not ready`.

Answer (score 6):

I ended up fixing this myself, see the exact steps below.

Note that there may be an easier solution but these steps definitely worked.

1. Make sure `network-manager` is the latest version (I have 0.9.6.0-0ubuntu7 ).
   You can check this with: `sudo dpkg -l | grep network-manager`
2. Right-click on Network Manager tray icon -> Edit Connections -> Wireless -> Add
   Manually add the parameters for connecting to your WLAN.
3. Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to set...
   `[ifupdown]
   managed=true`

   DO NOT restart `network-manager` service.
4. Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to deactivate the auto-start of your Wireless interface (probably called `wlan0`).
   For example:

   From this: `auto wlan0`
   .... to this: `#auto wlan0`
5. Run `/etc/init.d/network-manager force-reload`

Comment: Interesting. Commenting out `auto wlan0` should cause NetworkManager not to consider the interface an "autoconnect" interface. Yet you say that NetworkManager does bring it up automatically. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Did you by any chance also define the wireless connection using the  NM Connection Editor?

Comment: Guy, you are my savior: `managed=true` was exactly what I was sought for. My NM refuses to manage all a network connections, and I recalled that it was needed to turn it on in some config, but couldn't remember where.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04. Boot still takes forever with the message "Waiting for network configuration" and afterwards Network Manager and my wifi is still disabled. Nothing works until I manually run `nmcli nm wifi on`.

Comment: @jdthood I guess it is rather an issue with [poor NetworkManager documentation by Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager).

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall `wicd` if you intalled it along with `network-manager`

If both are installed at a time, then there will be a conflict and only one will be able to use the device at a time.